# airflow scheduler error: setting thread max to 1

Tags: airflow

I installed airflow 1.10 and I can run airflow webserver without any error, but when I run "airflow scheduler" I've got the below error:

{jobs.py:583} ERROR - Cannot use more than 1 thread when using sqlite. Setting max_threads to 1

following by this error:

sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: task_instance.executor_config

Here is the complete log:

```
[2018-12-28 22:59:04,556] {jobs.py:583} ERROR - Cannot use more than 1 thread when using sqlite. Setting max_threads to 1

[2018-12-28 22:59:04,562] {jobs.py:1545} INFO - Starting the scheduler

[2018-12-28 22:59:04,563] {jobs.py:1559} INFO - Processing files using up to 1 processes at a time

[2018-12-28 22:59:04,563] {jobs.py:1560} INFO - Running execute loop for -1 seconds

[2018-12-28 22:59:04,563] {jobs.py:1561} INFO - Processing each file at most -1 times

[2018-12-28 22:59:04,563] {jobs.py:1564} INFO - Process each file at most once every 0 seconds

[2018-12-28 22:59:04,563] {jobs.py:1568} INFO - Checking for new files in /Users/mtahe0806/airflow/dags every 300 seconds

[2018-12-28 22:59:04,563] {jobs.py:1571} INFO - Searching for files in /Users/mtahe0806/airflow/dags

[2018-12-28 22:59:04,588] {jobs.py:1573} INFO - There are 6 files in /Users/mtahe0806/airflow/dags

[2018-12-28 22:59:04,588] {jobs.py:1635} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs

[2018-12-28 22:59:04,590] {jobs.py:1590} INFO - Exited execute loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: task_instance.executor_config

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 928, in scheduler
    job.run()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 203, in run
    self._execute()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1588, in _execute
    self._execute_helper(processor_manager)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1636, in _execute_helper
    self.reset_state_for_orphaned_tasks()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 256, in reset_state_for_orphaned_tasks
    TI.state.in_(resettable_states))).all()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2703, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2855, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2878, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: task_instance.executor_config [SQL: 'SELECT task_instance.try_number AS task_instance_try_number, task_instance.task_id AS task_instance_task_id, task_instance.dag_id AS task_instance_dag_id, task_instance.execution_date AS task_instance_execution_date, task_instance.start_date AS task_instance_start_date, task_instance.end_date AS task_instance_end_date, task_instance.duration AS task_instance_duration, task_instance.state AS task_instance_state, task_instance.max_tries AS task_instance_max_tries, task_instance.hostname AS task_instance_hostname, task_instance.unixname AS task_instance_unixname, task_instance.job_id AS task_instance_job_id, task_instance.pool AS task_instance_pool, task_instance.queue AS task_instance_queue, task_instance.priority_weight AS task_instance_priority_weight, task_instance.operator AS task_instance_operator, task_instance.queued_dttm AS task_instance_queued_dttm, task_instance.pid AS task_instance_pid, task_instance.executor_config AS task_instance_executor_config \nFROM task_instance JOIN dag_run ON task_instance.dag_id = dag_run.dag_id AND task_instance.execution_date = dag_run.execution_date \nWHERE dag_run.state = ? AND dag_run.run_id NOT LIKE ? AND task_instance.state IN (?, ?)'] [parameters: ('running', 'backfill_%', 'scheduled', 'queued')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `executor` setting in the `airflow.cfg`. It must be `SequentialExecutor`, because it is the only executor supported while using SQLite.

Comment: executor mentioned is celeryExecutor, but still getting same Error as above